# Exact value infinte series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Please help.  I've gotten the answer as -log(3/2) in WolframAlpha, but have no clue how to work through it.  Thanks!

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  = \frac{(-1)^n}{n2^n}$

Comment: Often, you will get more help if you indicate anything that you DO know, about how to start, why certain things don't work, similar problems, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to recall that

$$-\frac1{1+r}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nr^{n-1}$$

And to integrate both sides (don't forget constant of integration), substituting $r=1/2$ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using the series expansion of [$\log(1+x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) :
$$
\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n} \quad\colon |x|\lt 1 \\
S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n 2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^n}{n}=-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)
$$